# Include only a domain path in multisite Network

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I want to install a WordPress Multisite Network.
I will include several Domains in it. Form one Domain, I want to include only a path mean:

```
www.mysite.com/wordpressblog
```

under  `www.mysite.com` a non wordpress installation shall run. 
In other words:

```
www.mysite.com/wordpressblog
```

Shall be a part of a multisite.

```
http://www.mysite.com/
```

Shall not be a aprt of the network.

Is  that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer you might hope for but is using a subdomain an option for you?

**www.mysite.com** - your non WordPress installation

**blog.mysite.com** - WordPress here

Subdomains give you even more options like separate DNS entries so the WordPress installation could run on a different server.

Comment: Nope. A subdomain is not an option for me....